# Print odd and even pages

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a jasper report that prints a card's front and back. In a A4 page 2 cards are printed.

The client now wants that in odd pages only front card's face is displayed. In even pages only cards back but in reverse order to ease printing.

What ways can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

```
Current report:
----------------
| Front | Back |
----------------

Desired outcome:
Odd page                 Even page 
---------------------    ------------------- 
| Front 1 | Front 3 |    | Back 3 | Back 1 |
| Front 2 | Front 4 |    | Back 4 | Back 2 |
---------------------    -------------------
```

Comment: I'd post-process the PDF produced by j-r using [pdftk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/).  In my experience [pdfjam](http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/statistics/staff/academic-research/firth/software/pdfjam/) is easier but it requires TeX/LaTeX,  your client may take exception...

Comment: A last resource solution but it did the trick. I was able to post process using pdftk or simply by printing pdf pages with doPDF. Thanks

Comment: Happy I've been useful! You may want to write down your procedure in an answer to share your new knowledge (and get upvoted...).

Answer (score 1):

You might try doing as follows:
Put the content of each band you want to differentiate inside frames.
Then you just need to use proper print when expression in order to print only the frame designed for the current page number.
The print when expression can be something like:

```
$V{PAGE_NUMBER} % 2 == 0
```

Which is true if the page is even and

```
$V{PAGE_NUMBER} % 2 == 1
```

which is true if the page is odd.

Comment: Thanks Endrik. How can I pass different lists to each detail band?